# How to set the repository my library depends into the artifact?

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've a Android library that generates an artifact. This library have some dependencies in itself that are resolved from jitpack, but currently, if the user of the library don't add jitpack to their dependency repoisitories my library will fail to resolve.

How can I add to my artifact the repositories it depends so the user that uses my library don't have to add jitpack to their dependencies?

This is the current code I use for publishing:

```
afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        repositories {
            maven {
                Properties properties = new Properties()
                if (project.rootProject.file('local.properties').canRead()) {
                    properties.load(project.rootProject.file("local.properties").newDataInputStream())
                }
                name = "GitHub"
                description = "PROJECT NAME"
                url = uri("PROJECT PRIVATE REPO URL")
                credentials {
                    username = properties.getProperty("REPO_PACKAGES_USERNAME") ?: System.getenv("REPO_PACKAGES_USERNAME")
                    password = properties.getProperty("REPO_PACKAGES_TOKEN") ?: System.getenv("REPO_PACKAGES_TOKEN")
                }
            }
        }
        components.all((component) -> {
            def componentName = component.getName()
            println("componentName: ${componentName}")
            def isDebug = componentName == "debug"
            publishing.publications.create("publication-$componentName", MavenPublication) {
                from component
                groupId = "com.foo.bar"
                version = "${android.defaultConfig.versionName}${isDebug ? '-DEBUG' : ''}"
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control the repositories of your consumers, as this would be a security vulnerability.

The best thing to do would be to publish your library to [maven central](https://central.sonatype.org/publish/publish-guide/), as this repository is almost universally used for Java dependencies.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I'm not the owner of one of the dependencies the library requires, so I can't upload it to mavenCentral but I had hope somehow this was possible.

Comment: You didn't add a lot of information, so I assumed that you were talking about your own library. If you are talking about managing the configuration for several projects under your (companies) control, then you can us a [Convention Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html) to share build logic, such as adding additional repositories.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. I've my own library that depends on other libraries but some of these dependencies are on jitpack and if the user from my library doesn't add jitpack it will fail to solve the dependencies.

Comment: What I'm talking about only works if you can bring your users to use a custom Gradle plugin, that adds the repositories, it does not suffice to just depend on your library.